# Salesforce limit for concurrent calls of Async Apex

Tags: batch, governorlimits, queueable-apex, asyncapexjob, apex-flex-queue

What is the limit of max concurrent calls for

1. Batchable apex
2. Queueable apex
3. Future methods

Need the Limit for both the scenarios 1. Limit for running the same batch (with different transactions), 2. Across all the batches in an org

Comment: hi @sautul , Please find the below article which shows all the limits .                                [link] (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apexgov.htm)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of governor limits that impact all async processes at the individual and org levels, all of which are covered in the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.210.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm) and [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apexgov.htm):

> Org level

Up to 250000 (or 200 x number of user licenses, whichever is greater) async transactions per day (in UTC).

> Batchable apex

You can have up to 5 batches executing concurrently, and up to a further 100 queued in the flex queue. If you try to add more to a full queue the request will simply fail.

Each batch uses 1 async for `start`, 1 for `finish` and one for each chunked call to `execute`.

> Queueable apex

Up to 50 queueables can be enqueued per sync transaction, or if done from async, only 1 can be enqueued.

Each uses one async.

> Future methods

Up to 50 futures can be queued per sync transaction, 1 from a queueable transaction and none from a batch or future.

Each uses one async.

---

There are many other limits you should consider, all covered in the documentation referenced above.

One interesting thing to note is that some limits are higher in an async context (including CPU and heap limits).

Another interesting point is that Platform Event execution (via trigger-based subscribers) is deemed sync and does not consume any of your async limits. There are, however, separate platform event limits.

Comment: Hi Phil, Thank you for the answer. In a scenario where I have places where I am using Batch Apex and Future method to achieve diff functionality, does both Future Method and batch Apex both are considered as combined as 100 in Flex Queue or flex queue is for batch apex only?

Comment: As above, only the batch is considered in the flex queue. Note, however, that you cannot call a future from a batch. Executing a batch from a future is permitted (but note this is then in an async context).